How to disable default predictive search in shopify store?
I'm trying to integrate our own predictive search in shopify store, and it's working fine too, but sometimes the default seach shows instead of our search.
i.e. if I'll make a search on shopify for "blue" this url come

https://react-hopify-store.myshopify.com/search?q=blue

Is there a way that I can disable this default predictive search of shopify for good.
